# coupling str elements from a list to a tuple list

Tags: python, list, tuples, element, coupling

I have the following list:

```
lines
['line_North_Mid', 'line_South_Mid',
 'line_North_South', 'line_Mid_South',
 'line_South_North','line_Mid_North' ]
```

I would like to couple them in a tuple list as follows, with respect to their names:

```
tuple_list
[('line_Mid_North', 'line_North_Mid'),
 ('line_North_South', 'line_South_North'),
 ('line_Mid_South', 'line_South_Mid')]
```

I thought maybe I could do a string search in the elements of the `lines` but it wont be efficient. Is there a better way to order `lines` elements in a way which would look like `tuple_list`

**Paring Criteria:**

If the both elements have the same Area_name: `('North', 'Mid', 'South')`

E.g.: `'line_North_Mid'` should be coupled with `'line_Mid_North'`

Comment: Is the ordering or your list reliable, i.e. adjacent items are always related?

Comment: What exactly is the paring criteria? How do you know which string goes with what other?

Comment: no the only related thing is if `'line_Mid_South'` is in the list, the `'line_South_Mid'` is also exists somewhere in the list

Comment: Is the start of the string (`line_`) always the same? Do the string always have 3 parts separated by underscores?

Comment: @Ralf it is always starting with `'line_'` and there is always `'_'` between `'South'` or `'North'`  or `'Mid'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

tuple_list = [i for i in combinations(lines,2) if i[0].split('_')[1] == i[1].split('_')[2] and i[0].split('_')[2] == i[1].split('_')[1]]
```

or I think this is better:

```
[i for i in combinations(lines,2) if i[0].split('_')[1:] == i[1].split('_')[1:][::-1]]
```

Comment: @oakca i Updated my answer and added a better solution.

Comment: it looks fine and actually 1 line code so I prefer this. But there is a question: does this work if I move the place of the elements in the lines list? @Mehrdad Pedramfar

Comment: @oakca Sure, it will check all of the possible combinations of your list elements.

Comment: This solution has quadratic complexity. The problem is solvable in linear time. There's no need to sequentially compare every string *with every other other*, e.g. see the `dict`-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

An order-agnostic O(*n*) solution is possible using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). The idea is to use as our dictionary keys the last 2 components of your strings delimited by `'_'`, appending values from your input list. Then extract values and convert to a list of tuples.

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = ['line_North_Mid', 'line_South_Mid',
     'line_North_South', 'line_Mid_South',
     'line_South_North', 'line_Mid_North']

dd = defaultdict(list)
for item in L:
    dd[frozenset(item.rsplit('_', maxsplit=2)[1:])].append(item)

res = list(map(tuple, dd.values()))

# [('line_North_Mid', 'line_Mid_North'),
#  ('line_South_Mid', 'line_Mid_South'),
#  ('line_North_South', 'line_South_North')]
```

Comment: will it work if I change the order of the elements in `lines` list?

Comment: @oakca, Yes, it will work. I have edited with your updated data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
lines = ['line_Mid_North', 'line_North_Mid',
         'line_North_South', 'line_South_North',
         'line_Mid_South', 'line_South_Mid']

[(j,i) for i in lines for j in lines if j not in i 
       if set(j.split('_')[1:]) < set(i.split('_'))][::2]

[('line_Mid_North', 'line_North_Mid'),
 ('line_North_South', 'line_South_North'),
 ('line_Mid_South', 'line_South_Mid')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a function that returns the same key for string that are supposed  to be together (a grouping-key).

```
def key(s):
    # ignore first part and sort other 2 parts, so they will always be in same order
    _, part_1, part_2 = s.split('_')
    return tuple(sorted([part_1, part_2]))
```

The you have to use some grouping method; I used `defaultdict` for example:

```
import collections

lines = [
    'line_North_Mid', 'line_South_Mid',
    'line_North_South', 'line_Mid_South',
    'line_South_North','line_Mid_North',
]

dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
for s in lines:
    dd[key(s)].append(s)     # those with same key get grouped

print(list(tuple(v) for v in dd.values()))
# [
#     ('line_North_Mid', 'line_Mid_North'),
#     ('line_South_Mid', 'line_Mid_South'),
#     ('line_North_South', 'line_South_North'),
# ]
```